# how to update data in page without reloade page

Tags: ajax

How can I do that on the Web site the number of unread messages is shown, and if a user
A new message without reloading the page gave me the number of unread messages is added?
In other words, the request to the database without loading the page results are shown?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading offsite content with AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489233/loading-offsite-content-with-ajax)

Comment: This did not please explain more fully explain this to flight attendants.

Comment: Here is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715493/loading-div-content-via-ajax-as-html